# Prove equality of cauchy schwarz if one vector is a multiple of other from this proof

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

[image]

I need to show that the inequality is an equality iff x is a multiple of y or the other way around and I have to make use of this proof presented.

So for the forward direction assume x is a multiple of y. Then there is some c where x-cy=0 so |x-cy|=0. Let t=c. Then 0 = |x-cy| = |x|^2 - 2c(x,y) + c^2|y|^2 = 0  We note the right side is a quadratic that is greater than or equal to 0, thus 0 must be the minimum and the quadratic achieves its minimum at t=c. And we note that t=(x,y)/|y|^2 is the minimum so plugging that in for t, we can carry out the same proof of the inequality but this time with the equal sign.

Backward direction
Assume |(x,y)|=|x||y|. How do I show that either x or y is a scalar multiple of the other?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that there is a $t$ for which $\|x\|^{2}-2t(x,y)+t^{2}\|y\|^{2}=0$ (by solving the quadratic) . This makes $\|x-ty\|=0$ so $x=ty$.

[In fact, $t=\frac {\|x\|} {\|y\|}$ will do].